# How to add a new entry to list retrieved from DB?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

What I have to do to be able add new entries in this list (retrieved from DB) from a xhtml page by open input fields `<h:inputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{x.editable}"/>?`

I retrieve data from sql db with List method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name= "user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable{
      static final String JDBC_DRIVER= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      static final String DB_URL= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/updateTesting";
      static final String USER= "****";
      static final String PASS= "****";
      static Connection connection;
      static PreparedStatement prepStatement;
      static List<Values> valuesList;
      static Values allValues;

private static List<Values> getUsers(){
        try {
            databaseConnection();
        String SQL= "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
        PreparedStatement prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        valuesList= new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
          boolean found= false;
          while(resultSet.next()== true){
              allValues= new Values();
              allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
              allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
              allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
              allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
              allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
              valuesList.add(allValues);
               found= true;
          }
          resultSet.close();
          prepStatement.close();
           close(connection);
          if(found){
              return valuesList;
          }else {
            return null;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in getUsers()-->"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return (null);
    }

    public List<Values> getInformation(){
        return getUsers();
    }
```

Here I'm trying to create new List and merge it with my List method getUsers(). When I click button `AddNew`, calling method `addNewUser()` must open input fields at the bottom of the list. Haven't any visible mistakes, all works, but nothing happens:

```
private List<Values> myList;

public List<Values> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

public void addNewUser(){
myList= getUsers();                      
allValues = new Values();             
allValues.setEditable(true);
myList.add(allValues);
}
```

xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
 <center>
 <h:dataTable value="#{user.information}" var="x" border="1" id="table">
    <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Id"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.id}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Order No"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Product name"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Price"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Quantity"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
 <h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{values.addNewUser}" update="table"/>
 </center>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You really need to narrow the amount of code down to the absolute minimum required, and be more explicit in what you are trying to achieve and what doesn't work. I have no intention of wading through a wall of code, and therefor I don't even know if your problem is with the JDBC side of things, or with the UI...

Comment: My problem is open 'input fields' on view page.

Comment: @ZhadovetsIvan So you mean on clicking addNewUser, control should come back to the same page but with blank values and with input fields as editable right? So what is happening in your case? User is coming back to the screen however the input fields are not editable?

Comment: Yes! I retreive DB data to dataTable, but can't open input fields for adding/editing!